# WoF not dropping its weapons, Breaker Blade, Clockwork Rifle and Laser Rifle

Tags: terraria

I've challenged the Wall of Flesh and emerged victorious twice, however it doesn't drop any weapons. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because it has a lot of drops and you aren't guaranteed to see those particular ones?

Answer (score 4):

The only drops which are guaranteed to spawn when you defeat the [WOF](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh) are healing potions and the Pwnhammer.

The rest of the drops (including weapons, emblems, and the WOF mask and trophy) only have a small chance of dropping.

The Breaker Blade, the Laser Rifle and the Clockwork Assault Rifle each only have a 1/6th (16.67%) chance of dropping.